# Can't find a codec for class org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, mongodb

```
 private void getUsersWithin24Hours(String id, Map < String, Object > payload) throws JSONException {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(payload.get("data")));
  Query query = new Query();

  query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("user_id").is(id).and("timezone").in(json.get("timezone")).and("gender").in(json.get("gender")).and("locale").in(json.get("language")).and("time").gt(getDate()));
  mongoTemplate.getCollection("user_log").distinct("user_id", query.getQueryObject());
 }
```

I was going to made a query and get result from mongodb and I was succeed with mongo terminal command:

```
db.getCollection('user_log').find({"user_id" : "1", "timezone" : {$in: [5,6]}, "gender" : {$in : ["male", "female"]}, "locale" : {$in : ["en_US"]}, "time" : {$gt : new ISODate("2017-01-26T16:57:52.354Z")}})
```

but from java when I was trying it gave me below error.

> org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find
>   a codec for class org.json.JSONArray

What is the ideal way to do this?

Hint : actually I think in my code error occurred of this part json.get("timezone"). because it contains array. When I am using hardcode string arrays this code works

Comment: Could you please provide your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: @MickaëlB actually it long 1072 lines. Can you tell me what do you want to know

Comment: Nerver mind. I'll provide a minimal answer to show you how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `JSONObject/JSONArray` for conversion.

Replace with below line if the `payload.get("data")` is `Map`

```
BasicDBObject json = new BasicDBObject(payload.get("data"));
```

Replace with below line if the `payload.get("data")` holds json string.

```
BasicDBObject json =(BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(payload.get("data"));
```

Comment: This looks ok. But I sloved this with pojo class

Comment: It depends on your use case. Yo';ll need add a codec if you want to use JSONObject/JSONArray as MongoDB dont have any knowledge of those types.

Comment: This is the Query genarate "{ "user_id" : "1" , "timezone" : { "$in" : [ [ "5" , "6" , "5.5"]]} , "gender" : { "$in" : [ [ "male" , "female"]]} , "locale" : { "$in" : [ [ "en_US" , "en_GB"]]} , "time" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2017-01-28T11:51:32.869Z"}}}" by 2nd option you gave . because array contain another array query did not work. any idea why?

Comment: Yes, but why do have array within array ? Is that your structure ?

Comment: no, I want ""timezone" : { "$in" : [ "5" , "6" , "5.5"]}" but code gives me like this "timezone" : { "$in" : [ [ "5" , "6" , "5.5"]]}"

Comment: Can you add a sample of your json before you parse and the updated code too ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of MongoDB from [MongoDB University course](https://university.mongodb.com/) with a MongoDB database named "students" with a collection named "grades" :

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**com/mongo/Main.java**

```
package com.mongo;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.*;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;

import javax.print.Doc;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClient client = new MongoClient();
        MongoDatabase database = client.getDatabase("students");
        final MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("grades");

        Bson sort = new Document("student_id", 1).append("score", 1);
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().sort(sort).iterator();

        try {
            Integer student_id = -1;
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                Document document = cursor.next();
                // Doing more stuff
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I think in my code error occurred of this part `json.get("timezone")`. because it contains array. When I am using hardcode string arrays this code works

Comment: I don't think so. Your exception `CodecConfigurationException` belongs to `org.bson` group and not `org.json`. I think your problem is that `json.get("timezone")` return `JSONArray` with is not supported in `Criteria` unless you have a specific codec. Can you try `json.get("timezone").toString()` instead ?